# Where can I find the key to the door in Mzulft Aedrome?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in Mzulft Aedrome and ran into this door, but apparently it requires a key.

Can it be found inside the dungeon or did I miss a quest when I entered this place?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is found within the Dungeon, in a chest guarded by a Dwemer Centurion.

[UESP has more](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Revealing_the_Unseen#Detailed_Walkthrough), but I'm not sure if you wanted to know the exact location or just an assurance that you're in the right place.

Comment: Actually I had killed the Dwemer Centurion, but I looked over the chest. I hate how these Dwemer chests looks like all the junk that's lying around...

Comment: Please show where the this cursed chest is. UESP does not have more, there is no pointer to the location there. A screenshot would be nice, plus the tick on the local map where it is. Just FYI, the Aedrome is said to be "cleared" for me, yet I struggle finding the key.

Answer (score 0):

The key is found at the right path where a Dwarven Centurion is. Since you killed it, go to the dwarven chest, open it, and you get the key for the door. Don't forget to loot other stuff too! And make sure you take the focus crystal from on of the Falmer.